# How to make multiple contenteditable divs turn green if word is correct?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordle-game

I have been trying to creating a wordle game for some time now, but I do not know how I would make it so if the word that the user inputs is correct, the boxes turn **green**. Same thing if the user inputs a letter that is correct but in the wrong position, it turns **yellow**. Lets say the word is "absolute", if the user guesses the word **absolute**, all boxes turn **green**, but if only one letter is correct from the user input, it turns only one box green or yellow depending on the position of the letter. Here is some of my code, I will link the rest below

```
   let keys = document.getElementById('keyboard-totality').querySelectorAll(".key-button");
   keys.forEach(key => {
       key.addEventListener('click', e => {
           if (e.target.id == 'DEL') {
               document.getElementById('amo1').lastChild.remove();
           }
           else {
               document.getElementById('amo1').innerHTML += (e.target.value + '</div>');
           }

       })

   });

function addOnNextElement(key,target){
       console.log(key);
       if(target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML == ""){
           target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = key;
       }
       else{
           addOnNextElement(key,target.nextElementSibling);
       }
   }


function clickFunction() {

 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[0].style.color = "red";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[1].style.color = "red";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[1].style.backgroundColor = "black";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[2].style.color = "red";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[2].style.backgroundColor = "black";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[3].style.color = "red";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[3].style.backgroundColor = "black";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[4].style.color = "red";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[4].style.backgroundColor = "black";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[5].style.color = "red";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[5].style.backgroundColor = "black";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[6].style.color = "red";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[6].style.backgroundColor = "black";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[7].style.color = "red";
 document.getElementsByClassName("amot")[7].style.backgroundColor = "black";

}
  document.addEventListener("keydown", KeyCheck);
function KeyCheck(event)
{
 var KeyID = event.keyCode;
 switch(KeyID)
 {
  case 8:

  event.target.previousElementSibling.focus();
  event.target.lastChild.remove();

  break;

  case 13:

  clickFunction(); ani();

  break;

  case 27:

  alert("Are you sure you want to leave?")
  window.close();

  case 46:

  event.target.previousElementSibling.focus();
  event.target.lastChild.remove();

  break;

  default:
  break;

}
```

}

Here is the rest of my code that includes the HTML, CSS, and JS: https://code.sololearn.com/WX59M6HHngc5
Edit: Added some more code to the sololearn project, thanks to c0dm1tu

Comment: The OP might have a look into the approach/solution of [_"Best way to track values of multiple text inputs to confirm they are all correct in a JavaScript ... word game"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71744854/best-way-to-track-values-of-multiple-text-inputs-to-confirm-they-are-all-correct/71759840#71759840) in order to maybe take some of the main ideas of handling events, state, behavior and appearance.

Comment: [https://codepen.io/codmitu/pen/LYegzNN?editors=0011](https://codepen.io/codmitu/pen/LYegzNN?editors=0011)

Comment: Thanks this is helpful but it only works for one div not multiple

Comment: Also the codepen.io only works in its own project, I have tried to put it into my code and edit it a bit, but no success

Answer (score 1):

A good beginning for your project would be to separate words by rows in your code to test them one by one.

```js
let answer = "word";

function checkLettersOfRow(row){
    let letters = row.getElementsByClassName("letter");
    for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if(answer.includes(letters[i].textContent)){
            if(answer.indexOf(letters[i].textContent) == i ){
                letters[i].classList.add("correct-place");
            }else{
                letters[i].classList.add("wrong-place");
            }
        }
    }
}

let rows = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
checkLettersOfRow(rows[0])
```

```css
.row .letter{
    display:inline-block;
}

.correct-place{
    color:white;
    background-color:green;
}
.wrong-place{
    color:white;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="letter">w</div>
  <div class="letter">i</div>
  <div class="letter">k</div>
  <div class="letter">i</div>
  <div class="letter">p</div>
  <div class="letter">e</div>
  <div class="letter">d</div>
  <div class="letter">i</div>
  <div class="letter">a</div>
  <div class="letter"></div>
  <div class="letter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll try to test it