# Is it possible that if a span is a certain color do something?

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers, event-delegation, custom-events

I want to make sure that when the span element turns lime, an alert box shows up, however, I tried using both hasAttribute() and getAttribute() to try to make the if statement function properly, but both did not work for me, the error may be occurring because the innerHTML is because configured in a forEach() function.

So far, when I click enter with the word "Absolute" put in the div boxes, the div boxes turn green, but no alert shows up.

Please help! Thank you in advance. Link to all lines of code just in case, sorry it may be a bit messy, I have a lot of code for a sololearn: https://code.sololearn.com/WX59M6HHngc5

```
const pText = document.querySelector("#p123").innerText.toUpperCase()
const button = document.querySelector("#ENTER")

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".amot")).forEach(function(element) {

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const text = element.textContent.toUpperCase()

  if (text.match(/\d/gi) || text.length < 1 || text.match(/[^a-z]/gi)) {
    element.innerText = text
    return
  }

  element.innerHTML = ""
  text.split("").forEach((letter, i) => {
    if (pText.includes(letter) && pText[i] === letter) {
      element.innerHTML += `<span id = "span1" style="color: lime">${letter}</span>`
    } else if (pText.includes(letter)){
      element.innerHTML += `<span style="color: orange">${letter}</span>`
    } else {
      element.innerHTML += `<span style="color: lightgrey">${letter}</span>`
    }
  })
})

let sp1 = document.getElementById("span1");

if(sp1.hasAttribute('style') == "color: lime") {

alert("Test");

};
```

Comment: hasAttribute returns a boolean.
You might want to look into [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead.

Comment: Why do u want to do this in such a messy way? Why dont you use `.style.color` for the condition

Comment: I recommend that you don't look at (or even use) the style attribute as different browsers render it differently:  `color:lime` `color: lime` `color: rgb(0,255,0)` `color: #00FF00` `color:#00FF00` etc.   Instead, use css and give it a class `<span class='match'>` then check for `if (sp1.classList.contains("match"))` (or so)

Comment: Alternatively, just add up the exact matches:  `var exactMatches = 0; if (pText.includes(letter) && pText[i] === letter) { exactMatches++; element.innerHTML... }` then just check the count.  Much simpler than messing about with styles/classes for program logic - keep your presentation separate from your logic.

Comment: Off topic: if `pText[i] === letter` then, *by definition* it will always match with `pText.includes(letter)` - so you don't need both checks.

Comment: The first question I have is, whether the OP is in control of the code. If so there is no need to make an additional action dependent on an UI change. Instead the state change should trigger the UI change and the additional change. Thus a possible clean approach was to dispatch a [_custom event_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) on _statechange_. In case of dealing with closed (third party) code there is still the possibility of utilizing a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above comment ...

> *"The first question I have is, whether the OP is in control of the code. If so there is no need to make an additional action dependent on an UI change. Instead the state change should trigger the UI change and the additional change. Thus a possible clean approach was to dispatch a [**custom event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) on **statechange**. In case of dealing with closed (third party) code there is still the possibility of utilizing a [**`MutationObserver`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver)"*

The [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) approach for code one does own and is allowed to change, and where decoupling makes sense ...

```js
const elmNode = document.querySelector('p')

elmNode
  // listen to an own custom event.
  .addEventListener('uiapprovalchange', evt => {
    if (evt.detail.isApproved) {

      console.log('text color should have changed into an approval state');
      // console.log({ evt: { detail: evt.detail } });
    } else {
      // console.clear();
    }
    console.log({ evt: { detail: evt.detail } });
  });

elmNode
  .addEventListener('click', ({ currentTarget }) => {
    const { dataset } = currentTarget;
    const doApprove = (dataset.approved !== 'true');

    dataset.approved = String(doApprove);
    currentTarget.style.cssText = doApprove ? "color: lime" : '';

    // create and dispatch an own custom event.
    currentTarget.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent('uiapprovalchange', {
        detail: {
          isApproved: doApprove,
        },
      }),
    );
  });
```

```html
<p>click in order to toggle the <em>approved</em> color change</p>
```

The [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) approach for code one does not own and thus can not change/adapt to ones needs ...

```js
function handleMutation(recordList, observer) {
  recordList.forEach(({ type, target, attributeName }) => {
    if (
      // assure correct mutation.
      type === 'attributes' &&
      attributeName === 'style' &&
      target.matches('body > p')
    ) {
      // normalize css text value.
      const text = target.style.cssText.replace((/\s+/g), '');

      if (text.includes('color:lime')) {
        console.log('text color should have changed into an approval state');
      } else {
        console.clear();
      }
    }
  });
}
const targetNode = document.querySelector('p');
const options = { attributes: true };

const observer = new MutationObserver(handleMutation);
observer.observe(targetNode, options);

targetNode
  .addEventListener('click', ({ currentTarget }) => {
    const { dataset } = currentTarget;
    const doApprove = (dataset.approved !== 'true');

    dataset.approved = String(doApprove);
    currentTarget.style.cssText = doApprove ? "color: lime" : '';
  });
```

```html
<p>click in order to toggle the <em>approved</em> color change</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but how would I make it so only IF all the letters in a certain row of divs are lime an alert box pops up? This code will be helpful to me for something else I was looking for in my project, but if possible please check my sololearn out. https://code.sololearn.com/WX59M6HHngc5

Comment: @Infui0ayaan ... you are welcome, and yes, you are already asking another, entirely different question. Both approaches inform you about the latest ui change. And since the OP seems to mis/use the DOM as a model the OP has to continue from the last UI-changed target-node querying all the related other nodes in order to read their `... style.cssText` values as well (the OP can use the code from the 2nd observer example). But of cause it was best to create an own model of the *wordle* game in order to easily keep track of all the state changes.

Comment: Alright, thank you for walking me through CustomEvent and MutationObserver, I really appreciate the help, and sorry if I asked for a lot.

Comment: @Infui0ayaan ... Regarding the modeling and the data/dom binding, just have a look into ... [_"Best way to track values of multiple text inputs to confirm they are all correct in a JavaScript ... word game"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71744854/best-way-to-track-values-of-multiple-text-inputs-to-confirm-they-are-all-correct)

Comment: Sorry forgot that

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native CSS event in JavaScript.
The only option here is to periodically check the color.

For example:

```js
const targetColor = '#ff0000';
const elementId = 'my-elem';

const checkColor = () => {
  const myElem = document.getElementById(elementId);
  const color = getComputedStyle(myElem).color;
  if (color && color.toLowerCase() === targetColor) {
    alert('Color has been changed.');
  }
}

setInterval(checkColor, 500);
```

##### Pitfalls

However, for this to work, you must know the exact color you're looking for, and specify it in the right format. You'll also need to add your own checks to ensure the element is found, and the CSS property is found, to prevent an error. Don't forget to also clear the setInterval when you're finished with it. Also keep in mind, that the user can manually change the color of the element, and then trigger your event.

##### Alternative

Using a frontend framework, like React or Vue would make the exercise significantly easier. You could manage the element's color with a data attribute, then just watch that attribute for changes without the need for setInterval.

Another option would be restructuring the app, so that events are triggered based on a user interaction, and those same events set the class (or color) of a given element.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the fast answer, though for some reason this will not work for me, is there any way this piece of code could be modified? Thanks again, and sorry for asking more.

Comment: Sure, but can you share what specifically isn't working? Do you get an error message?

Comment: `TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
at checkColor`

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the answer (to remove `window.____` preceding getComputedStyles), it should now work :)

Comment: For some reason it still will not work for me, I am getting the same message when `window.___` was removed. Which is strange, there is no instance of window. in the block of code but an error is still occurring when the program is run.

Comment: Yes, the code saved in the sololearn document shows the exact same error with and without window. My sololearn has more code, but it may be a bit messy...

Also, I was not the one who downvoted your answer.

Comment: Also just to clarify, when I try to capitalize the W in window, a new error shows up: 

TypeError: Window.getComputedStyle is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244024/discussion-between-infui0ayaan-and-lissy93).