# Beginner Javascript OOP Approach to Not Repeating Code

Tags: javascript, wordle-game

I've attempted to make a WORDLE clone and I'm aware that repeated code is bad.

```
if (guess === 1){
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        inpAsArray.push(userInput[i])
        let ele = document.getElementById(`${i + 1}`)
        ele.innerText = inpAsArray[i]
        
        if (!sw.includes(inpAsArray[i])){
            ele.style.color = 'red'
        }

        if (sw.includes(inpAsArray[i])){
            ele.style.color = 'yellow'
        }

        if (inpAsArray[i] === sw[i]){
            ele.style.color = 'green'
        }
    }
    
    console.log(inpAsArray)
    input.value = ""
    inpAsArray = []
}
```

This is a chunk of code that I have written in which it will push the users input guess into an array and it will select the corresponding p tag within a div so the guess can be inputted to the screen, now I have this code repeated for if (guess = 2) up until the 6th guess these 6 if statements take up around 130 lines of code which I imagine isn't considered very good. Below I will leave the second if statement to show the difference between the two is the id selector.

```
if (guess === 2){
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        inpAsArray.push(userInput[i])
        let ele = document.getElementById(`${i + 6}`)             ''' THIS IS TO SELECT THE FIRST P TAG OF 
        ele.innerText = inpAsArray[i]                             ''' THE SECOND ROW
        
        if (!sw.includes(inpAsArray[i])){
            ele.style.color = 'red'
        }
        if (sw.includes(inpAsArray[i])){
            ele.style.color = 'yellow'
        }
        if (inpAsArray[i] === sw[i]){
            ele.style.color = 'green'
        }
    }
    
    console.log(inpAsArray)
    input.value = ""
    inpAsArray = []
}
```

A second problem I have is that for the ele.style.color = 'yellow' if statement, if the word selected from the dictionary is donut, and the user inputs dazed, the program will make the first d green and aze red and then the last d yellow as it is present within the string but not in the correct place despite the d already being marked as correct, I thought about checking to see if the letter has already been discovered within the string and having a counter case but the problem with that is if a word has many repeating characters.

What I have tried is detailed above (if statements with individual value comparisons for each guess)

In SHORT my main question is how can I cut down the if statements to accomodate for all 6 guesses without repeating the IF statement 6 times while also having a difference within the `` let ele = document.getElementbyId(`${i + 6}`) `` being different each time

Comment: maybe someone will read it all, but if u do this u'll get more changes to be helped - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: *OOP* and *not repeating code* can be entirely different topics.

Comment: One thing: doing `if (!something)` immediately followed by `if (something)` should be an `if ... else` with a single test (unless "something" can change in between, which in your case here doesn't happen).

Comment: You can make that block into a function, and then whenever you require the color, you can just run the function.

Comment: Maybe you just need to put it in a loop for each row and select the element at `i + 1 + (row * 5)`  (Or if it's based on `guess` then `i + 1 + 5 * (guess - 1)`)

Comment: To answer the `my main question is how can I cut down the if statements to accommodate for all 6 guesses without repeating the IF statement 6 times` question: you may only want to do that if, *logically*, all of the condition's success (`truthy`) cases are executing the same statement. To achieve that you can use `&&` (logical AND operator) inside the `if`'s conditions. But, your *code logic* is executing different statement in each if statement respectively, so the answer is: no, you can't do that. Also the conditions following the first `if(statement)` should have the `else if` clause.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, while its not the best code, I've cut it down from 200 lines to 113 by making the block into a callable function passing in the num to reference the starting id of each row!

Comment: The OP might get some inspiration from something similar like an approach to the ["wheel of fortune"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71744854/best-way-to-track-values-of-multiple-text-inputs-to-confirm-they-are-all-correct)